# Oracle SimpleJdbcCall fails with 0 while running stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

There is an oracle stored procedure:

test_owner.pkg_xyz.daycalculation(p_parameter = >"Tuesday");

My Simple JDBCCall to call Oracle procedure:

```
  public class StoredExecuter {
     *fields*

   public void ExecuteDailyProced (String dayId) {
      try {
           String slqPackage = "pkg_xyz";
           String procName = "daycalculation";
           SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                  .withSchemaName("test_owner")
                  .withCatalogName(sqlPackage)
                  .withProcedureName(procName)
                  .declaredParameters(new SqlParameter(dayId,OracleTypes.Varchar));
            jdbcCall.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
            jdbcCall.execute();
          }
       catch(Exception e) {
          throw new RunTimeException("Cannot perform procedure due to : " +e.getMessage(),e);
           }
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot perform procedure due to : 0
      as tests.StoredExecuter.ExecuteDailyProced......
      Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
      at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters(CallMetaDataContext.java:577)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters(AbstractJdbcCall.java:442)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:376)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:188)
```

Appreciate any help to resolve this problem!
Thank you

Comment: Add quotes at end 
.withCatalogName("sqlPackage)

Comment: HI @PrateekMishra, deleted quotes, it was just misprint here and it does not cause the exception.